# Validation Error in APIM Policy for Websocket

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add policy to the websocket endpoint in Azure API Management through ARM template but I am getting error

```
"error": {
    "code": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Not allowed at 'Api' scope for 'WEBSOCKET' api type"
}
```

I am able to add the policy manually, but I am unable to add the policy to web socket through ARM template. I have tried the same policy to web api its successful.

ARM template for just policy I was trying to see if it can be deployed after the websocket is provisioned:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "ApimServiceName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "policypath": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "Environment": {
      "type": "String"
    },
  },
  "variables": {
    "env": "[concat('test-', parameters('Environment'))]",
    "svc": "[concat('testsvc-', parameters('Environment'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/policies",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('ApimServiceName'), '/', variables('env'), '/policy')]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "value": "[parameters('policypath')]",
        "format": "rawxml-link"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

entire arm template which I used to deploy both websocket and policy is [here](https://gist.github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/0a682439000f2819b9e2bb4c19a05f73)(I have tried to directly add the policy instead of sas link for policy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure out a workaround, when I directly add the policy to the operation it works. even then, I have to write the policy directly in the same file the arm template way of providing the file with SAS is not working. here is the current version of code.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "value": "<!--\r\n    IMPORTANT:\r\n    - Policy elements can appear only within the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend> section elements.\r\n    - To apply a policy to the incoming request (before it is forwarded to the backend service), place a corresponding policy element within the <inbound> section element.\r\n    - To apply a policy to the outgoing response (before it is sent back to the caller), place a corresponding policy element within the <outbound> section element.\r\n    - To add a policy, place the cursor at the desired insertion point and select a policy from the sidebar.\r\n    - To remove a policy, delete the corresponding policy statement from the policy document.\r\n    - Position the <base> element within a section element to inherit all policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.\r\n    - Remove the <base> element to prevent inheriting policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.\r\n    - Policies are applied in the order of their appearance, from the top down.\r\n    - Comments within policy elements are not supported and may disappear. Place your comments between policy elements or at a higher level scope.\r\n-->\r\n<policies>\r\n  <inbound>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </inbound>\r\n  <backend>\r\n    <retry condition=\"@(context.Response.StatusCode &gt;= 400)\" count=\"2\" interval=\"1\" first-fast-retry=\"true\">\r\n      <choose>\r\n        <when condition=\"@(context.Response != null &amp;&amp; context.Response.StatusCode &gt;= 400)\">\r\n          <set-backend-service base-url=\"wss://\" />\r\n        </when>\r\n        <otherwise />\r\n      </choose>\r\n      <forward-request />\r\n    </retry>\r\n  </backend>\r\n  <outbound>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </outbound>\r\n  <on-error>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </on-error>\r\n</policies>",
    "format": "xml"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations/policies",
  "apiVersion": "2022-04-01-preview",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('ApimServiceName'), '/', variables('env'), '/onHandshake/policy')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis', parameters('ApimServiceName'), variables('env'))]"
  ]
},
```